# Finding unique triangles given in n number of triangles in python

Tags: python-3.x

Given n-number of triangles, we are required to find how many triangles are unique out of given triangles. For each triangle we are given three integers a, b and c (the sides of a triangle).

A triangle is said to be unique if there is no other triangle with same set of sides.

Sample Input:

```
7 6 5
5 7 6
8 2 9
2 3 4
2 4 3
```

Sample Output:

```
1
```

Explanation:

Each line is a triangle with 3 sides given. The first two triangles are identical since they have similar sides (just the orders are different). ie. the sum of all the sides for both triangles are equal.

The third triangle '8 2 9' is unique since no other triangle has the exact similar sides. So the output is 1 (total number of unique triangles)

Sample Input:

```
34 5 32
15 20 6
4 2 3
5 6 9
15 20 6
34 5 32
```

Sample Output:

```
2
```

Here the triangles '423' and '560' are unique. So the output is 2 (total number of unique triangles)

This is what I did...

```
n = int(input())
arr = [list(map(int, input().split())) for x in range(n)]

def uniqueTriangle(arr):
  row = len(arr)
  col = len(arr[0])
  mp = {}
  hel = {}

  for i in range(row):
    tri = arr[i]
    tri.sort()
    strA = [str(x) for x in tri]
    strB = ''
    strB = strB.join(strA)
    if strB not in mp.values():
      mo[i] = strB
    else:
      hell[i] = strB

  count = 0
  for i in range(row):
    if i in mp:
      val = mp.get(i)
      if val not in hel.values():
        count = count + 1

  print (count)
```

Apologize for the ugly code. But how can I make this code better?

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is a problem definition, not really a question. Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: A question like this should not belong here, but on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

arr = [[7, 6, 5],[5, 7, 6],[8, 2, 9],[2, 3, 4],[2, 4, 3]]

def unique_triangles(arr):
    counter = Counter([frozenset(a) for a in arr])
    return len([res for res in counter if counter[res] == 1])
```

1. Use `frozenset` to mark each unique set of triangle
2. use `collections.Counter` to count the number of unique sets found in the input array
3. return the set appeared only once

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did :

```
n = int(input())
l=[]
for i in range(n):
    t = [int(side) for side in input().split()]
    l.append(set(t))

ans=[]
for j in l:
    count=0 
    for i in l:
        if i==j:
            count+=1
    if count==1:
        ans.append(j)

print(len(ans))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).